# Formatting a shell command output

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

i just have a simple question on the output of the shell command.The below command lists all the directory owners directory name and create time and source how can i makes this look neati.e, how do i format it

```
find /disk/ui -name '.user.log'|xargs cat 
rtty        Demo1           Tue Mar  6 17:45:29 IST 2012
    /disk/ui/gh
nk    wee             Tue Mar  6 15:15:25 IST 2012
              /disk0116/ui/gg/
rtty        Test_sklgfx_main                Wed Mar 14 15:17:12 IST 2012
    /disk/ui/dtr2/
DH        Test_repo               Thu Mar 15 14:03:36 IST 2012
    /disk/ui/_dtr1
```

Also can i add a label on the top saying owner directory name created time and source.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use

```
find /disk0116/ui -name '.user_repo.log'|xargs cat | column -t
```

Comment: @Rajeev, try to add echo "xxx xxx xxx" && at the begin of your command. Maybe you should add "()"at the right place. and the "xxx"means what it should be.

Comment: Use a command grouping construct: `{ echo "header ..."; find ... | xargs cat; } | column -t` -- the spaces around the braces and the semicolon after 'cat' are required.